# How to limit questions to 3 but still have it random

Tags: java, android

so I'm coding an app on where it ask questions for one of it's activities in android studio. It's only 3 questions however it keeps repeating over and over again. I want to make after it ask the 3 questions it stops and if possible give the points the player earned (That's not my main goal but it would be nice)

This is the activityB.java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {

Button btn_one, btn_two, btn_three, btn_four;
TextView tv_question;

private Question question = new Question();

private String answer;
private int questionLength = question.questions.length;

Random random;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

    random = new Random();


    btn_one = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_one);
    btn_one.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_two = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_two);
    btn_two.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_three = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_three);
    btn_three.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_four = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_four);
    btn_four.setOnClickListener(this);

    tv_question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_question);

    NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));

    Button button2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent MainActivity = new Intent (ActivityB.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(MainActivity);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Welcome Back!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_one:
            if(btn_one.getText() == answer){
                Toast.makeText(ActivityB.this, "You Are Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
            }else{
                GameOver();
            }

            break;

        case R.id.btn_two:
            if(btn_two.getText() == answer){
                Toast.makeText(ActivityB.this, "You Are Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
            }else{
                GameOver();
            }

            break;

        case R.id.btn_three:
            if(btn_three.getText() == answer){
                Toast.makeText(ActivityB.this, "You Are Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
            }else{
                GameOver();
            }

            break;

        case R.id.btn_four:
            if(btn_four.getText() == answer){
                Toast.makeText(ActivityB.this, "You Are Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
            }else{
                GameOver();
            }

            break;
    }
}

private void GameOver(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityB.this);
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Game Over")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("New Game", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   // System.exit(0);
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                }
            });
    alertDialogBuilder.show();

}

private void NextQuestion(int num){
    tv_question.setText(question.getQuestion(num));
    btn_one.setText(question.getchoice1(num));
    btn_two.setText(question.getchoice2(num));
    btn_three.setText(question.getchoice3(num));
    btn_four.setText(question.getchoice4(num));

    answer = question.getCorrectAnswer(num);
}

}
```

This is the Question.java

```
  public class Question {
   public String questions[] = {
                 "Which city is the second largest city in Denmark?",
        "The meaning of Aarhus?",
                 "When was the oldest Viking settlement founded in Aarhus?"
            };

public String choices[][] = {
                    {"Copenhagen", "Esbjerg", "Aarhus", "Odense"},
                   {"Wolf's ears", "The Mouth of the River", "City of Warriors", "Wisdom"},
                    {"770AD", "1000AD", "845AD", "793AD"}
};

public String correctAnswer[] = {
        "Aarhus",
        "The Mouth of the River",
        "770AD"
};

public String getQuestion(int a){
    String question = questions[a];
    return question;
}

public String getchoice1(int a){
    String choice = choices[a][0];
    return choice;
}

public String getchoice2(int a){
    String choice = choices[a][1];
    return choice;
}

  public String getchoice3(int a){
    String choice = choices[a][2];
    return choice; }

  public String getchoice4(int a){
         String choice = choices[a][3];
     return choice;
    }

  public String getCorrectAnswer(int a){
    String answer = correctAnswer[a];
       return answer;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**you have init new Integer counter and increment by click any button and check counter is greater then 3 so stop you game and don't forgot counter default value 1 like this**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    count++;
    if(count > 3){
     //game End
    }else{

       switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_one:
            if(btn_one.getText() == answer){
                Toast.makeText(ActivityB.this, "You Are Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
            }else{
                GameOver();
            }

            break;

        case R.id.btn_two:
            if(btn_two.getText() == answer){
                Toast.makeText(ActivityB.this, "You Are Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
            }else{
                GameOver();
            }

            break;

        case R.id.btn_three:
            if(btn_three.getText() == answer){
                Toast.makeText(ActivityB.this, "You Are Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
            }else{
                GameOver();
            }

            break;

        case R.id.btn_four:
            if(btn_four.getText() == answer){
                Toast.makeText(ActivityB.this, "You Are Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
            }else{
                GameOver();
            }

            break;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit onClick like :

```
public void onClick(View v){
if(((Button)v).getText()==answer){
Toast.makeText(ActivityB.this, "You Are Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if(count<question.length()){
NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
}
else{
//The player is now the master !
}

}
else{
//Game over
}
}
```